# How can I develop for Ubuntu Touch on Windows?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I am working in a windows environment and need to develop applications in ubuntu.  what is the best approach?

Comment: What do you want to develop?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend installing a virtual machine. With ubuntu on it, or dualbooting Windows wit Ubuntu.

Comment: I would also recommend using something with Ubuntu Touch on as well...